# GoJS Item (Node) selection via key

Tags: angular, typescript, gojs

Using typescript in Angular, how can I select a node from diagram using its key ?

When I create a new node, I have to Left click it with a mouse in order to select it, I want it to be selected right away.

Which Function do I have to call on my diagram in order to select the node that has key "1", here is what I tried, but doesn't seem to work:

```
selectItem(item: any) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.myDiagram.select(this.myDiagram.findNodeForKey(item.key));
    if (this.selectedItem['toPort']) {
      this.selectedItemtype = 'Link';
      this.myDiagram.select(this.myDiagram.findLinkForData(item));
    } else {
      this.selectedItemtype = 'Node';
      this.myDiagram.select(this.myDiagram.findNodeForKey(item.key));
    }
    // this.rerender();
}
```

I drop an Item from a tree and have 2 windows, diagram window and a property window (in which I edit the properties of a node), I need to be able to edit properties right on drop for the dropped item, but it seems that if I edit the item, and than click on the dropped item, they are not the same anymore, and previously edited Item is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically right, but unnecessarily complicated.  But either you're doing it twice (if it's a node) or you might not find the link if it isn't the same link data object in the model.

If you have enabled keys for links in your **GraphLinksModel** by setting **GraphLinksModel.linkKeyProperty**, this should be sufficient:

```
if (item.toPort !== undefined) {
  myDiagram.select(myDiagram.findPartForKey(item.key));
} else {
  myDiagram.select(myDiagram.findNodeForKey(item.key));
}
```

If you haven't enabled maintaining unique keys for link data, you'll need to do what you did for links:

```
myDiagram.select(myDiagram.findLinkForData(item));
```

BUT that again depends on your *item* being the same object reference as what's in the **GraphLinksModel.linkDataArray**.  If it is not the same pointer, you might want to call **Diagram.findLinksByExample** and pick one.

Regarding property editors, are you using a DataInspector, https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.html ?  If so, that should just work.  If you have implemented your own HTML elements for editing properties, perhaps you have the wrong reference.  You should be showing/editing the properties of the first Part in the **Diagram.selection**.  When the user drops a new copy of a Node when dragged from another Diagram (or the same Diagram), the new copy will be in the **Diagram.selection** collection.